# Problems connecting to remote MySQL database

Tags: mysql, local

When I try to connect to a remote mysql database I receive an error saying I was unable to log into my router's mysql database.

```
tom@main:~$ mysql -u appleton -p -h 85.17.xxx.xx
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'appleton'@'85.210.169.xxx' (using password: NO)
```

Even though I am specifying my IP (85.17.xxx.xx) in the argv the error message is showing my Router's external IP (85.210.169.xxx)

I discovered this whilst using `DBI->connect` in perl.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: That clearly means you don't have permission or some password issue maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'appleton'@'85.210.169.xxx'` is supposed to show your host, not the database's host. It's your full identifier (username@host) for mysql to determine if you are allowed to connect. Do you have sufficient rights to connect to the database from your IP? Access can be granted to users so that they can only connect from localhost for example.

[MySQL Docs on Users](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

Comment: I thought I allowed access from any host but it turns out I needed to change a setting in my.conf